# Playing main timeline in Flash CC Html5 Canvas

Tags: animation, html5-canvas, createjs, flash-cc

Does anyone know the Flash CC/Html5 Canvas conversion for:

```
MovieClip(root).play();
```

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Animations exported from Flash CC have an `exportRoot` global variable, which is essentially the root movie clip, which is added to the stage. You should be able to target it from anywhere:

```
exportRoot.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out myself. If your movieClip is on the main time line, within that movieClip you would use the following code:

```
this.parent.play();
```

'parent' can be used multiple times for lower tiers, such as:

```
this.parent.parent.play();
```